# Passing a variable or another variable if first is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to pass a variable, but if it is undefined, pass `'undefined'` instead:

```js
`**AFK Channel:** ${targetGuild.afkChannel.name}, ${targetGuild.afkChannelId || 'undefined'}`
```

Which I thought would pass `'undefined'` if `targetGuild.afkChannelId` is undefined. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Within the backtick code, please change: `${targetGuild.afkChannelId || 'undefined'}` to this: `${targetGuild.afkChannelId ? targetGuild.afkChannelId : 'undefined'}` and share feedback on what happens, please.

Comment: what is currently being passed when its undefined?

Comment: @jsN00b I attempted that but it says that `targetGuild.afkChannel` is null (which it is) and it stops there.
It looks like this: `${targetGuild.afkChannel.name ? targetGuild.afkChannel.name : 'undefined'}`

Comment: Use optional chaining. Instead of `targetGuild.afkChannel.name`, try with: `targetGuild?.afkChannel?.name ?? "undefined"`